# do most ide users work directly on the local copy of code from an scm?

Tags: eclipse, git

if one is using an scm and ide like say, git and eclipse, then is it more common to work directly on a local copy of the code using the ide or do some developers take a copy of the local copy to work on and once they complete their changes migrate those to the working copy for eventual integration into the repo?

is this just an unnecessary step that doesn't provide any benefit?

additionally, are there any ide files that are kept in scm with projects on certain teams? say, in case a team had standardized work on a certain ide? or are these file regularly stripped out for the repo?

Comment: That depends. If you want to specify project-specifically e.g. what's an error, warning or what to ignore or how to format, you have to share the Eclipse-specific `.settings` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, devs work on their local copy of the repo and do not copy it another time.

This is because, if they have done something wrong, they can simply revert the changes to the scm state.

So, copying the local copy is unnecessary.

Sometimes all IDE files are cut out of the repository because these files are not needed for everyone (or if the team uses different IDEs.

Automatically generated (IDE) files are normally cut out of the repository too.

If you use a package manager like maven, IDE files are autogenerated too, so they are left out too.